# How to use values of elements with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out how to use Jquery to alert "Text" only when the "Yes" radio button is clicked.

The problem with my code, is that the alert shows also when the "No" button is clicked.

As you see, I also added a checkbox with a comment, to make it clear.

If you can, please help me, how to fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
  if($('input[name=one][value =yes]:checked')) {
    alert("Text");
  }
  
  if($('input[name=two][value =no]:checked')) {
    // alert("Text");
  }
  
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Show text?</p> 
<input type="radio" name="one" value="yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="one" value="no">No


<p>Do somthing Else</p> 
<input type="checkbox" name="two" value="no">No
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `this` keyword to retrieve the `value` from the radio which raised the event. Then you can simply read its value in the `if` condition, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
      console.log("Text");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Show text?</p>
<input type="radio" name="one" value="yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="one" value="no">No

<p>Do somthing Else</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="two" value="no">No
```

Note the use of the `change` event over `click` for accessibility reasons, and also `console.log()` instead of `alert()` for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
  if($('input:radio[name="one"]:checked').val() =="yes") {
  
    alert("Text");
  }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Show text?</p> 
<input type="radio" name="one" value="yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="one" value="no">No


<p>Do somthing Else</p> 
<input type="checkbox" name="two" value="no">No
```